# How does the OS resolve a request to connect to 0.0.0.0?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

As I understand 0.0.0.0 means all network interfaces of this host (including 127.0.0.1).

Suppose I have three interfaces 192.0.2.40, 203.0.113.150 and 127.0.0.1 on some host (OS linux).

On 192.0.2.40:777, I have ServerA. On 203.0.113.150:777, I have ServerB. How does the OS resolve a request to connect to 0.0.0.0? I mean when the same port (777) is listening on different interfaces what server(ServerA or serverB) and why will be connected when I will do in terminal  of `this` host `telnet 0.0.0.0 777`

Comment: @DavidPostill Could you say, is there information why linux OS redirects 0.0.0.0 to localhost in duplicate that you gave? I don't see, do you?

Comment: Agreed, the so-called duplicate is anything but.

Answer (score 11):

Officially, it only means that as a source address (i.e. when *binding* a socket to a local interface). As the destination address it doesn't have this meaning – it's technically an illegal address.

However it seems that originally BSD treated it **as a loopback connection** and Linux carries it on:

- UNIX System Manager's Manual – Changes to the Kernel in 4.3BSD – [section 7.1 (SMM:13-21)](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/mtXinu/MT_XINU_SMM_Apr_1986.pdf#page=464) (`/usr/doc/smm/13.kchanges` within the 4.3BSD source tree):

  > **in_pcb.c**
  >
  > The destination address of a *connect* may be given as INADDR_ANY (0) as a shorthand notation for “this host.” This simplifies the process of connecting to local servers such as the name-domain server that translates host names to addresses.

Within Linux, an all-zeros IPv4 destination is handled in `net/ipv4/route.c` at route lookup time:

```c
struct rtable *ip_route_output_key_hash_rcu(...) {
    ...
    if (!fl4->daddr) {
        fl4->daddr = fl4->saddr;
        if (!fl4->daddr)
            fl4->daddr = fl4->saddr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
        dev_out = net->loopback_dev;
        fl4->flowi4_oif = LOOPBACK_IFINDEX;
        res->type = RTN_LOCAL;
        flags |= RTCF_LOCAL;
        goto make_route;
    }
    ...
}
```

Which translates to "If destination is empty, fill it in with 127.0.0.1 and route via the `lo` interface". The OS pretends that you tried to connect to localhost.

The same in IPv6 is handled at protocol level (individually by TCP and UDP). For example, `net/ipv6/tcp_ipv6.c` contains:

```c
static int tcp_v6_connect(...) {
    ...
    /*
     *  connect() to INADDR_ANY means loopback (BSD'ism).
     */
    if (ipv6_addr_any(&usin->sin6_addr)) {
        if (ipv6_addr_v4mapped(&sk->sk_v6_rcv_saddr))
            ipv6_addr_set_v4mapped(htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK),
                           &usin->sin6_addr);
        else
            usin->sin6_addr = in6addr_loopback;
    }
    ...
}
```

Meanwhile in `net/ipv6/udp.c`:

```c
int udpv6_sendmsg(...) {
    ...
    if (!ipv6_addr_any(daddr))
        fl6.daddr = *daddr;
    else
        fl6.daddr.s6_addr[15] = 0x1; /* :: means loopback (BSD'ism) */
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So, in my example when I do `telnet 0.0.0.0 777` I will get connection refused. However, if I also had a ServerC on `127.0.0.0:777` I would connect to ServerC. Do I understand it right?

Comment: I don't accept your answer as this is theory, but not the concrete answer to concrete question.

Comment: For a question "how does the OS [...]", the source code of that OS is as concrete as it could possibly get.

Comment: @PavelK The answer is both concrete and correct and you should accept it.

Comment: @JennyD You never give up, don't you? However, that's enough. You can downvote but I won't.

Comment: @PavelK I followed the question here because I was interested in the answer, and have upvoted the answer. I'm sorry that my attempts to be of assistance were so clumsy that I offended you; it was not my intention and I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose I have three interfaces 192.0.2.40, 203.0.113.150 and 127.0.0.1 on some host (OS linux).

I created two adapters like the following commands to create virtual apapter `eth1` for one of IPs:

```
sudo modprobe dummy
sudo ip link add eth1 type dummy
sudo ip addr add 203.0.113.150/24 dev eth1
sudo ip link set dev eth1 up
```

All my requests to `0.0.0.0` goes to those application who binds `127.0.0.1`. If I stopped it, then I see `Connection refused` error (even applications on 203.0.113.150 is running).

I believe that @user1686's answer is right and it routes only to loopback interface that is `127.0.0.1`.